# Adding TextProgressBar in xml layout : "Error parsing xml"

Tags: android, xml

I´m using this Tutorial http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/ 
to implement a progressbar with text into my app. 
I encountered following Problem though: 
in my xml file it says: "Error parsing xml: unbound prefix"

here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test2.ChattingActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

     <View
        android:id="@+id/Line1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

     <com.example.test2.TextProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarWithText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:progress="70"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
        components:textSize="18dp"
        components:textColor="@android:color/black"
        components:text="Loading 70%" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTopic"
        style="@style/buttongreywhite"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_labels"
        android:onClick="openTopicFragment"
        android:text="@string/topics" /> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLike"
        style="@style/buttongreywhite"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_good"
        android:onClick="likeWhatYouSaid"
        android:text="@string/like" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Line2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonTopic"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

the modified progressbar class is located in com.example.test2
it´s name is TextProgressBar

What am i missing here? There are no other errors in any of my xml files. 
I didnt find any answers concering my problem so far. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `components` prefix is undefined for your `TextProgressBar`.

Based on the tutorial you linked you should have the following in your `RelativeLayout`

```
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test2"
```

Comment: this worked for me : xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test2"

thank you very much

Comment: @user3457769 ah yes, meant to put your actual package name. Edited. No problem!